# mapping xml with XSLT : CDATA blocker

Tags: xml, xslt

I was trying since forever to get the content of the element "test" from the following xml file using XSLT but I am really blocked.

Do you please have an idea how to get it using XSLT

The XML file content is the following :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <BusinessResponse>
         <BusinessResult><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test>helloWorld</test>]]></BusinessResult>
      </BusinessResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you trying to produce the XML `<test>helloWorld</test>` or the text `helloWorld`? What version of XSLT are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **XSLT 3.0** you can use the [`parse-xml()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml) function to parse the text as XML and then you can XPath into the structure to obtain either the `<test>` element or it's `/test/text()` text node:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="parse-xml(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/BusinessResponse/BusinessResult)/test"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With **XSLT 1.0** or greater, if your content is really that simple, and you only want the text node inside of the `<test>` element, you could use `substring-before()` and `substring-after()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of 
        select="substring-before(
                  substring-after(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/BusinessResponse/BusinessResult,
                     '&lt;test>'), 
                  '&lt;/test>')" />            
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you need to be able to perform something more sophisticated and need the full power of XSLT and XPath, then you could achieve this with two transforms. The first transform to serialize the `text()` of the `BusinessResult` as XML by using `xsl:value-of` with `disable-output-escaping="yes"` :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/BusinessResponse/BusinessResult" disable-output-escaping="yes" />            
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test>helloWorld</test>
```

If you wanted that with other XML structure while processing the SOAP Envelope, then you may need to exclude the XML declaration:

```
substring-after(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/BusinessResponse/BusinessResult,'?>')
```

And then use a second XSLT to select and process what you want from that XML output

Comment: a very efficient explication and solution.Thank you so much

Comment: Hello Mads, is it possible to do it with the same xslt file with wslt version 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="BusinessResult" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```